# Approach for encrypting user data with user password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption

I have the following requirement:
Users on my site have some sensitive data, meaning that ONLY the owner user should be able to read it. In other words: I have to make sure that not even the site/sql administrators can (human) read the content.

I am trying to implement the following approach:
When saving the data, encrypt it by using the user password. When serving the data to the user, decrypt it using the user's password. I can handle the password-change scenario by re-encrypting the user data. However, the issue is that the only time I have the user password is during Loging-In and I am not sure it's a good idea to 'hold on to it' by storing it in the user profile in-mem object.

So, how would I go about such requirement? Again - the goal is that only the user should be able to en/decrypt their data on the fly. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: The way i've seen this implemented is by requesting the user to input the password when he needs to access the sensitive data section

Comment: Or, use the user's password to en-/decrypt the actual encryption key only. This way, upon password change, you have to only re-encrypt the key, plus you don't need to hold on to the password during the session to do the actual user's data cryptography. In addition, this has the advantage that you can generate a secure encryption key at registration, so that the security of the encryption itself is not limited by the quality of the password.

Comment: @HannoBinder, let me see if I understand: when the user registers, create a random encryption key ONLY for that user. Use this key to crypto the sensitive data. When the user logs in, decrypt the encryption key, store it in memory and use it to encrypt/decrypt the user's sensitive records. When user changes password, re-encrypt the encryption key. Am I getting it right? We achieve isolation, in terms that even a specific user gets hacked, the rest of the users are not compromised. Right?